# Magento - keep product stock quantity at 0 when reached but still allow backorders

Tags: magento-1.7

We have a Magento multi-store installation. We would like to prevent product stock levels from going below "0" when 0 quantity is reached but still allow those products to be purchased. When a product is sold out, we simply drop-ship it from another company. The main goal is to not have negative counts in the inventory. Currently, when a product is dropped shipped because we're out of stock, we have to manually change the stock quantity back to "0" from "-1" in the product's inventory field. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on how to make this happen.

Thank you,

Jim